# How to input data in excel/csv to make multiple chart in R studio

Tags: r, ggplot2, input, line, multiline

I have a data here, [my data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hmsriS5oEHppyBcfq2USQItK0JKGy4LL/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=105108842885523802309&rtpof=true&sd=true).
I would like to make graph like this [example multichart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3eAE.png).
I have tried to run this script below.
However, I dont understand how to input my data in excel to run this script.
Does anyone to help me? Please, I have thought about this 3 days and The deadline is very soon. Thank you for your help

```
# Libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(babynames) # provide the dataset: a dataframe called babynames
library(dplyr)
library(hrbrthemes)
library(viridis)

# Keep only 3 names
don <- babynames %>% 
  filter(name %in% c("Ashley", "Patricia", "Helen")) %>%
  filter(sex=="F")
  
# Plot
don %>%
  ggplot( aes(x=year, y=n, group=name, color=name)) +
    geom_line() +
    scale_color_viridis(discrete = TRUE) +
    ggtitle("Popularity of American names in the previous 30 years") +
    theme_ipsum() +
    ylab("Number of babies born")
```

Answer (score 0):

You may read the data using `readxl::read_excel`, get it in long format and plot using `ggplot`.

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- readxl::read_excel('example data.xlsx')

data %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -row, values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(row, value, color = name) + 
  geom_line()
```

[image]